# getFontColorObject() not returning correct color hex on Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a function which will return the text color of a specified cell. But it never returns the correct color of the cell and instead always returns "#ff000000" no matter the text color of the cell. an example of someone useing the function is "=fontColor("A1:A1")".
`

```
function fontColor(a) {
  var b=a;
  if(b==undefined){
    b="A1:A1";
  }
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var range = sheet.getRange(b);
  
  return range.getFontColorObject().asRgbColor().asHexString();
}
```

`

I tried using "Logger.log" to see if the function worked and tried the function in a google sheet but both times it returned "#ff000000". I tried this on cells which had text colors of blue and ones which had text colors of black. I was expecting the function to return the correct color for example it should return "#000000" for black and "#0000ff" for blue.

Comment: The question is incomplete, because we don't see real cells and their font colors and the Logger output and how this function is called. Please provide additional info to check the problem.

Answer (score 2):

> var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

No matter what range string you send, only the first sheet's range is returned.

```
=fontColor("A1")
```

in `Sheet3` will only return the first sheet's `A1`'s color. Try directly calling `getRange()` on spreadsheet:

```
var range = ss.getRange(b);
```

Then you can try:

```
=fontColor("Sheet3!A1")
```

Note that the [return value as per docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/rgb-color.html#asHexString()) is

> Returns the color as a CSS-style 7 character hexadecimal string (#rrggbb) or 9 character hexadecimal string (#aarrggbb).

If 9 character `#aarrggbb` string is returned, the first `aa` is the alpha/transparency channel.

Comment: I Change 'var range = sheet.getRange(b);' to 'var range = ss.getRange(b);' and then did '=fontColor("History!A1")' (history is the name of one of my sheets) but it still returned #ff000000 while the text color was #000000

Comment: @Ian55603 the first `ff` can be ignored. It stands for alpha or transparency. See edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the problem I was having has nothing to do with the code but rather with google sheets. If you never change the font color manually or just keep the font color as the default black then it will return an incorrect value, but if you change the color manual then it will return the correct value. Example: if you change the color to cyan then it will correctly return "#00ffff" and if you change the color back to black then it will correctly return "#000000", but if you never change the color and leave it at the default black then it will return "#ff000000". My best guess is that the default value of the font color of a cell is "#ff000000" and wont represent the correct color code until you manually change it.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the line :

```
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
```

And replace :

```
var range = sheet.getRange(b);
```

By :

```
var range = ss.getRange(b);
```

This is working for me on the current sheet I use it :

```
function fontColor(a) {
  var b=a;
  if(b==undefined){
    b="A1:A1";
  }
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = ss.getRange(b);
  
  return range.getFontColorObject().asRgbColor().asHexString();
}
```